# which HDD caddy for my Dell Inspiron N5110

Tags: ssd

I'm planning on adding an SSD to my old DELL Inspiron N5110, using a caddy to put the SSD there instead of the optical drive, but I don't know the size of the caddy that I should buy, 9.5mm or 12.7mm

My laptop's optical drive is a "TSSTcorp DVD+-RW SN-208BB", I searched all over the net and I didn't find it's size.

Is it a problem if I get a bigger or a smaller caddy?

Comment: What size did you buy? 12.7 or 9.5? I am also planning, pls let me know.

Comment: @vijayinani as I mentioned in the answer below, I bought the 12.7mm

Comment: Sure. Thanks. You mentioned 12.7. I was confused as you said you can use 9.5 too. What goes wrong if I use 9.5? Does it stay loose? How 12.7 is better than 9.5

Comment: 12.7 is just the right size for my laptop, nothing wrong with 9.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I asked some repair shops, the right size for the N5110 is 12.7mm, but you can still use the 9mm too

Comment: dont know why people gave negative points. +1 from me. Valid question. I will go for 12.7 one

Answer (score 1):

The CD/DVD RW Drive dimensions in Dell Inspiron N5110 laptop are **128(W) x 12.7(H) x 126.1(D) mm**.

The Model No. is **DS-8ACSH**.

More Info. can be found from this official link: **http://www.liteonodd.com/datasheet/DS-8ACSH_Datasheet_EN.pdf**

Many people were not sure about the right size of caddy for Dell N5110. **Hope this helps.**

**The right caddy height is 12.7 mm**.